# JavaFX: passing Arguments to a Self-Contained Application does not work

Tags: java, javafx, bundle, packaging

My application is bundled/packaged as native application. Since JDK 8u40 it should be possible to pass arguments to a bundled application. But this is not working.

Outcome directory:

- app directory
- runtime directory
- msvcp100.dll
- msvcr100.dll
- packager.dll
- MyApp.exe
- MyApp.ico

When I call MyApp.exe from Windows Explorer the application starts as JavaFX GUI application. In my main() method I have a switch when passing argument do something else (in this case do a system.out.println). When I call "MyApp.exe Hallo test", then nothing happened. The GUI is not starting also. I do not believe that my main() method is being called, because I have put an other system.out.println right after entry point of this method.

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#JSDPG995

See chapter 7.3.6 Passing Arguments to a Self-Contained Application

it should work out of the box.

So what is wrong? Where is my output?

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` method may not be called when launched as a native app, you should do all your argument parsing either within your application's `start` method, or you can follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33549932/1715829) for force your `main` method to be called.

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm):

> The main() method is not required for JavaFX applications when the JAR file for the application is created with the JavaFX Packager tool, which embeds the JavaFX Launcher in the JAR file. However, it is useful to include the main() method so you can run JAR files that were created without the JavaFX Launcher, such as when using an IDE in which the JavaFX tools are not fully integrated. Also, Swing applications that embed JavaFX code require the main() method.