# JavaFX not calling main(String[] args) method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I've developed program that can be executed as `GUI` and `CLI` depends on parameters are provided. Here is application class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("cli")) {
            String pathToProperties = args[1];
            Cli cli = new Cli(pathToProperties);
            cli.loadPropertiesAndGenerateApk();
        } else {
            launch(args);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view/sample.fxml"));

        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Allowed Site Configurator");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And when I build artifacts Intellij IDEA create `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
JavaFX-Version: 2.2
JavaFX-Application-Class: sample.Main
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Main-Class: com/javafx/main/Main
```

When I call `java -jar JavaFXApp.jar "cli" ~/config.properties` program invoke only `start()` method without calling `main()` method first.

Question is: How to force to call `main()` method first?

Comment: How do you know for sure that it is bypassing the main method? Have you tried adding something in there at the start of the program to see if it's running? (a beep/println/display something)

Comment: @phflack because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503220/javafx-program-doesnt-run-in-nogui-command-line-mode and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160947/why-is-main-method-used-in-javafx-application-when-start-already-exist/24161007#24161007

Comment: Looks like that manifest is to blame.  Your main class is com.javafx.main.Main, which is bypassing your class's `main` method.  I would look into whether your IDE will let you override the manifest;  the only line the manifest needs to have is `Main-Class: sample.main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a separate class for the GUI:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("cli")) {
            String pathToProperties = args[1];
            Cli cli = new Cli(pathToProperties);
            cli.loadPropertiesAndGenerateApk();
        } else {
            Application.launch(GUIApp.class, args);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class GUIApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view/sample.fxml"));

        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Allowed Site Configurator");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

and configure the build so that `Main` is the main class.